# systemctl status shows vendor preset: disabled

Tags: rhel, systemd, rpm

Could someone please clarify what "vendor preset : disable" means? This option is  visible after enabling a package in RHEL7.

Answer (score 30):

If you see a Vendor preset: Disabled, it means when the service first installs it will be disabled on start up and will have to be manually started. If you want the service to start up automatically with boot up, all it takes is to change it's start up setting with `systemctl enable <service>`, example: `systemctl enable httpd`.

A detailed explanation can be found at [RHEL systemctl documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/System_Administrators_Guide/sect-Managing_Services_with_systemd-Services.html) or [systemctl man page itself](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html)

```
● httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2018-09-10 09:29:16 MDT; 1h 3min ago
     Docs: man:httpd(8)
           man:apachectl(8)
  Process: 6917 ExecReload=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -k graceful (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 1261 (httpd)
   Status: "Total requests: 0; Current requests/sec: 0; Current traffic:   0 B/sec"
   CGroup: /system.slice/httpd.service
           ├─1261 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ├─6936 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ├─6937 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ├─6938 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ├─6939 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           └─6940 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND

Sep 10 09:28:51 localhost systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Sep 10 09:29:16 localhost systemd[1]: Started The Apache HTTP Server.
Sep 10 10:21:02 localhost systemd[1]: Reloaded The Apache HTTP Server.
```

Comment: I could see even before enable the package, i see the option "vendor preset: disabled". Any reason behind?.

Comment: it's just showing the default start up settings for the service. Whether the service is enabled or disabled.

Comment: How to change that "vendor preset: disabled" setting?

Comment: Its set by the service owners, its good for showing what was the default setting for the services.

Comment: So in other words, it doesn't indicate the current state of a service (whether it's enabled or disabled), it's just the default state of the service when it's first installed.

Answer (score 4):

Taken from the [systemd man](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html) page:

> (...) if a unit file has no vendor-supplied version (i.e. is only defined
>   below /etc/systemd/system or /run/systemd/system, but not in a unit
>   file stored below /usr), then it is not removed. Also, if a unit is
>   masked, it is unmasked.

If the vendor uses SystemD it is recommended for the Vendor to configure the installation of the SystemD files in `/usr` so it will act as default in case the user wants modify the file.

An example of a vendor enabled systemd file:

```
● sshd.service - OpenSSH server daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/sshd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss TZ; 1h 0min ago
     Docs: man:sshd(8)
           man:sshd_config(5)
 Main PID: 12345 (sshd)
   CGroup: /system.slice/sshd.service
           └─12345 /usr/sbin/sshd -D

MMM DD HH:mm:ss XXXXXX systemd[1]: Starting OpenSSH server daemon...
MMM DD HH:mm:ss XXXXXX systemd[1]: Started OpenSSH server daemon.
```